# Need help for syntax

Tags: php, object, syntax

I'm looking for the kind to access at the value of an array directly from the object's method.

For example :

With this syntax, no problem :

```
$myArray = $myObject->getArray();

print_r($myArray[0])
```

But to reduce the number of line in source code, how to get the element directly with the method ?

I do that, but it's not correct :

```
$myArray = $myObject->getArray()[0];
```

Comment: Why would you want to reduce the number of lines in your source?

Comment: Just to know if it's possible to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on php 5.4 (which support array dereferencing) you can do the second option:

```
$myArray = $myObject->getArray()[0];
```

If you are on PHP < 5.4 you can "fix" it in the class (of which the object is a instance):

```
class Foo
{
    public function getArray()
    {
        return $this->theArray;
    }

    public function getFirstItem()
    {  
         return $this->theArray[0];
    }
}

$myObject = new Foo();
print_r($myObject->getFirstItem());
```

Answer (score 3):

The following is only available for [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/releases/5_4_0.php) and supposedly higher.

```
$myArray = $myObject->getArray()[0];
```

Unfortunately there is no quicker way below PHP 5.4.

See [@deceze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11340383/1157493) for a good alternative.

Answer (score 2):

For PHP 5.3-:

```
$myArray = current($myObject->getArray());
```

or

```
list($myArray) = $myObject->getArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

> But to reduce the number of line in source code, how to get the element directly with the method ?

Although it *is* possible to achieve this in PHP 5.4 with the syntax you've demonstrated, I have to ask, why would you want that? There are ways of doing it in 5.3 in a one-liner, but I don't see the need to do this. The number of lines is surely less interesting than the readability of the code?

Comment: You're right, but it's just for my "own" culture (and to increase my comprehension of OOP)

Comment: @bahamut100 There's no rule in OO stating that everything should be on one line.

Answer (score 0):

IT IS IMPOSSIBRRUUU.

Serious answer:
sadly it is not possible. You can write a very ugly wrapper like this:

```
function getValue($arr, $index)
{
    return $arr[$index];
}

$myArray = getValue($myObject->getArray(), 0);
```

But that makes less readable code.

*read other answers about php 5.4 Finally!*